# Trouble connecting to friend's Pocket Edition Lite server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend is on his Samsung Galaxy tablet, and I'm on my iPod 5th gen. It's not letting us be on the same server. We are both using the same WiFi. I have Minecraft PE and my friend has PE Lite. When I go to "join game" and click on his server name, it says *locating server*. But after a few moments it says *could not connect to server* and returns *try again*. Why isn't it letting me?

Comment: It is possible that Minecraft PE doesn't support cross-platform play (either both of you need to play on iOS device, or Android device)

Comment: Okay, from what I procured from the wiki: The multiplayer mode is cross-platform compatible between Android and iOS, but not Demo/Lite with Full version

Comment: What game do you have?  If it's Demo/Lite, I don't think it'll work. On the other hand, as the wiki says, if you both have Full version, it should work.

Comment: Yeah its saying it is cross-platform compatable, but not with the lite version, which my friend has... Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89461/1351

Answer (score 3):

Your friend has the lite version, as you stated above.

The Minecraft Pocket Edition wikia says:

> The multiplayer mode is cross-platform compatible between Android and
>   iOS, but not Demo/Lite with Full version

Basically, both of you need to have the Full version in order to play with each other. Or you could both use the lite edition .