# Pocket Edition server problems

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minecraft Pocket Edition: Trouble connecting to friend’s server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102855/minecraft-pocket-edition-trouble-connecting-to-friends-server)

So my sister and I both bought Minecraft Pocket Edition version 6.1. Every time I make a server and she joins, it disconnects after a while or just as she joins. We are both using the same WiFi. It's worked In the past and it will only not disconnect if I play on a server she has created. I have a Android and she has a iPod. What's going on?

Comment: What versions are you two using? If one or the other has a demo version, servers will not work.

Comment: Hey, there's a known bug that's been discovered a few months ago - certain Android devices, especially the Kindle Fire 2nd generation, have problems hosting LAN games. This has come up after the closing of the question, so I thought I'd let you know.